# Azure WebJob logging issue

Tags: azure, logging, azure-webjobs

I'm having trouble with my Azure WebJob and I'm trying to determine where (if) the log is dumping out so that I can troubleshoot the issue(s).

I'm using .NET7, and have the following in Program.cs:

```
builder.ConfigureLogging( b =>
{
    b.AddConsole();
    b.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics();
} );
```

I have Logging:LogLevel:Default set to Information and Logging:LogLevel:Microsoft.AspNetCore to Warning.

I then have functions later with QueueTrigger parameters to run as needed by my App Service.  Namely, when I need to send an email.  The message gets added to the queue by the AppService - I can see that.  It then falls into the -poison queue, so it is getting seen and processed by the WebJob - it's just failing.  There are some times if I manually add a message to the queue (via the portal) that it will succeed, but that's been a little hit or miss.

Nothing shows up in the logs within the portal (Web Jobs -> Logs -> Toggle Output) regarding the queue message being triggered - whether it works or not.  I've tried enabling "App Service logs" for both "Filesystem" and "Blob".  Neither shows any Web Job information.

Any ideas what I'm missing?  If I could get an error message to work on, I could try to solve what's going on.  Thoughts?

**EDIT**

Small update - I could probably figure out how to get ILogger to dump messages and get something out of it.  Maybe.  But, in previous versions of my WebJobs (with Framework 4.8), I would get messages like

> Executing 'Functions.CheckEmails' (Reason='New queue message detected
> on 'queue-name'.', Id=9d5e4c3a-0a2d-4da1-85b0-1887d816e7a7)

in my logs without having to do anything.  They came directly out of the app getting run.  And, when a queue message failed and dropped into the poison queue, I'd get details there as well.  How do I get that working again in .NET 7?

Comment: Could you please share your `appsettings.json` and `.csproj` file.

Comment: Please share the code of your Function?

Comment: So you want to log the messages only by adding `builder.ConfigureLogging(....` am I correct ?